# s3fs mount error: specified passwd_file is not readable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I am trying to port ftp server on linux ec2 instance.
Password authentication file exists in /etc/passwd-s3fs with permission 600.
But when I run command:

`$ s3fs bucketname /home/s3/s3mnt -o passwd_file=/etc/passwd-s3fs,nonempty`

It shows below error:

`s3fs: specified passwd_file is not readable.`

Also tried with permission 640 but same issue. Kindly help.

Comment: I think you need to use `passwd_file` (underline) rather than `passwd-file` (hyphen).

Comment: Sorry, correction I am using ```$ s3fs bucketname /home/s3/s3mnt -o passwd_file=/etc/passwd-s3fs,nonempty```

Comment: can you try with detail debugging -o dbglevel=info -f -o curldbg or try with removing nonempty

Comment: Could you run ls -l /etc/passwd-s3fs?

Answer (score 2):

After you check the permissions - make sure that the credentials file use the correct format.

If you're using `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

If you're using other credentials file (i.e. `${HOME}/.passwd-s3fs`):

```
ACCESS_KEY_ID:SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

---

Additional information from the AUTHENTICATION section in [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/s3fs.1.html):

```
   The  s3fs  password  file  has  this  format  (use this format if you have only one set of
   credentials):
       accessKeyId:secretAccessKey

   If you have more than one set of credentials, this syntax is also recognized:
       bucketName:accessKeyId:secretAccessKey

   Password files can be stored in two locations:
        /etc/passwd-s3fs     [0640]
        $HOME/.passwd-s3fs   [0600]
```

---

**Last check:** Ensure that you're passing absolute path of the `.passwd-s3fs` or executing the `s3fs` command from the relative path. 
I was stuck on that without noticing the path.

Answer (score 1):

run the following command

```
sudo chmod 640 /etc/passwd-s3fs
```

and remove the ",nonempty" from the command line, it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, if setting the right permissions to the files isn't work, try to change the owner of the file. Run the `ls -la` to see who is the owner:

```sh
total 224
drwx------ 8 ec2-user ec2-user    224 out 19 17:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root         51 out 15 20:40 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user     25 out 19 17:43 .aws
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user   1343 out 16 20:12 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user     18 jan 16  2020 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    193 jan 16  2020 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    231 jan 16  2020 .bashrc
drwx------ 4 ec2-user root         41 out 19 15:57 .cache
drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user     87 out 19 17:16 images
-rw------- 1 root     root         62 out 19 17:29 .passwd-s3fs
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user   4096 out 19 16:45 s3fs-1.74
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 199120 jan 23  2016 s3fs-1.74.tar.gz
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user     29 out 15 20:40 .ssh
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    989 out 19 17:43 .viminfo
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user     28 out 19 16:10 work
```

In my case, the passwd file is owned by the root, what's causing the permission denied. Change the file owner like `sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user .passwd-s3fs` and then list the files again with `ls -la`:

```sh
total 224
drwx------ 8 ec2-user ec2-user    224 out 19 17:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root         51 out 15 20:40 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 ec2-user ec2-user     25 out 19 17:43 .aws
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user   1343 out 16 20:12 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user     18 jan 16  2020 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    193 jan 16  2020 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    231 jan 16  2020 .bashrc
drwx------ 4 ec2-user root         41 out 19 15:57 .cache
drwxrwxr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user     87 out 19 17:16 images
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user     62 out 19 17:29 .passwd-s3fs
drwxr-xr-x 5 ec2-user ec2-user   4096 out 19 16:45 s3fs-1.74
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 199120 jan 23  2016 s3fs-1.74.tar.gz
drwx------ 2 ec2-user ec2-user     29 out 15 20:40 .ssh
-rw------- 1 ec2-user ec2-user    989 out 19 17:43 .viminfo
drwxrwxr-x 4 ec2-user ec2-user     28 out 19 16:10 work
```

How didi you see, the owner was change and now the command will run as well.